# Echo row from mysql table as results from html dropdown value

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have db table with three columns `id`, `club` and `percent`, and about a hundred rows.

First stage I want to populate html dropdown list with value from `club` column, and that is ok I did it, but in second stage I don't have any idea how to link value from the dropdown list with a specific row in table?

Any help would be appreciated.

This is code of first part which is ok:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
    include 'server.php';
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $sql = "SELECT id, club, percent FROM sometable"; 

?>
    <form action="por.php" method="post">
        <select name="home">
            <?php                   
                foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {

                    echo "<option value=" .$row['id']. ">" .$row['club']. "</option>";  

                }
            ?>
        </select>
                <br><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

---

EDIT
OK, I will try to be clearer:
1. this is my table:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7evVD.png)

2. this is populated list with above code:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaylA.png)
3. So, now I want to do this: if I choose e.g. Ciclon I want to diplay "Ciclon 55", or if I choose bolivar to display "Bolivar 37"...
   I know how to this if type $variable for each option, and in code for each option type if/elseif, but i want to populate list with value from table and later to display selected option, I dont want to type hundred and hundred lines.
   I hope its clear now.

Comment: You should add "method=post" to your opening form tag. Then on por.php you can access the $_POST['home'] variable which is the id of the row in sometable

Comment: To get specific rows from db table you can use "where" clause in your query.

Comment: Try something like this  _
    $sql = "SELECT id, club, percent FROM sometable where percent > 60"; _

Comment: please make the question clear what you really need?

Comment: @Sanooj T I edited question, hope its clear now.

Comment: You want to display ciclon55 in your dropdown? if thats what you needed then its simple.

Comment: @Funk Doc I forgot to type "method=post" in question  in code I was typed, but dont know how to type code in por.php file (see edited part of question)

Comment: you want that value after submit?

Comment: @Sanooj Yes I want that value after submit

Comment: please check  the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you needed.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
include 'server.php';
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 $home=$_POST['home'];
//To find the club and percent of the selected id
 $sql = "SELECT  club, percent FROM sometable where id=".$home; 
 $row=  $conn->query($sql);
 echo $row['club'].$row['percent']
}

$sql = "SELECT id, club, percent FROM sometable"; 

?>
 <form action="por.php" method="post">
    <select name="home">
        <?php                   
            foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {

                echo "<option value=" .$row['id']. ">" .$row['club']. "</option>";  

            }
        ?>
    </select>
            <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, thats it, I just had to put fetch_assoc();  between  $row =  $conn->query($sql); and echo $row['club'].$row['percent']. Thanks a lot.